How do I get the folder of the unzipped archive with ZipFoundation
As the title says, how do I get the unarchived folder from a zip folder extracted with ZipFoundation?
I want to show the extracted file/folder with the click of button ("Show in Finder") after it's done being extracted.
I have the following code:
func ShowInFinderButton() -> some View {
    Button {
        if let destination = destinationDirectory {
            NSWorkspace.shared.activateFileViewerSelecting([destination])
        }
    } label: {
        Text("Show in Finder")
    }
}

but the destinationDirctory is not what I want as it shows the folder that encloses the original archive.
EDIT:
Ok, it seems my question isn't clear enough, what I'd like to do is to select an archive, be able to do something like this:
let archiveEntry = archive.first //so that I don't have to hard code a path here 

currently I have to do something like this:
let archiveEntry = archive["containing_directory/"]

again this is hard coding the path and requires knowledge of how the archive is structured.
Any advice on how to do so would be greatly appreciated.

destinationDirectory is just an url, you can update it with the name of the file/folder, or whatever you like.

fair, but I want to get the name of the folder that was extracted from the archive and have no idea how to do that.
